# Can VBA code update a cell in a column of an Excel worksheet when a user enters data in a specific column range?

Tags: excel, vba, offset, worksheet, automatic-updates

I have an Excel worksheet that is 12 columns wide and many rows deep. I'm trying to write a Worksheet_Change Sub that will cause the worksheet to automatically put in the current Date/Time, using the Now function, to Column L (or 12) in the same row that data was changed in a cell in columns A-K or 1 through 11.

So far I have tried using the Offset function to accomplish this, but I can only find success in doing relative updates and not partially absolute updates. I tried using the Choose function in order to replace the offset function variable for column shift based on what cell the user is Targeting, but I can't get that to work either. Right now I'm attempting to use this, but to no avail:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range

Offst As Integer
End Type
Set WorkRng = Range("A:K")
If Not Application.Intersect(WorkRng, Range(Target.AddressLocal)) _
Is Nothing Then
If Target.Column = 1 Then Offst = 11
ElseIf Target.Column = 2 Then Offst = 10
ElseIf Target.Column = 3 Then Offst = 9
ElseIf Target.Column = 4 Then Offst = 8
ElseIf Target.Column = 5 Then Offst = 7
ElseIf Target.Column = 6 Then Offst = 6
ElseIf Target.Column = 7 Then Offst = 5
ElseIf Target.Column = 8 Then Offst = 4
ElseIf Target.Column = 9 Then Offst = 3
ElseIf Target.Column = 10 Then Offst = 2
ElseIf Target.Column = 11 Then Offst = 1
End If
    With Offst
            Target.Offset(0, Offst).Value = Now
            Target.Offset(0, Offst).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy AM/PM"
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm very basic with VBA, and I don't have many hours behind it. I've searched the internet quite a bit, and I'd like to think I'm pretty good at exhausting search engines but I can't find something that directly relates to my situation. I can only find examples of people updating a single column of data, not a Range.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: There's no nee for the `with` also, `offst=12-target.column` would get rid of all the if's

Comment: What is the `End Type` doing there.

Comment: As @BigBen says was there a type, which offst was part of, as it also has no `Dim`

Comment: Sorry Guys I've been getting different errors in my code as I try to change things little by little. It's lead me down a rabbit hole where this probably is further than from where I started. The current Error I receive when execute this code is "Compile Error: Statement invalid outside of Type block. So I thought I had to construct a Type Block for my Variables and That's the point at which I came here. @BigBen

Comment: I was getting errors saying I needed a With Statement @Nathan_Sav  Big Nooby here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an offset. You can hard-code the `L` and use `Intersect` along with `Target.EntireRow` to update the corresponding rows in column L.

Simplified, the entire code could be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Me.Range("A:K"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Intersect(Me.Columns("L"), Target.EntireRow).Value = Now
    Intersect(Me.Columns("L"), Target.EntireRow).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy AM/PM"
End Sub
```